# XSL transformation to HTML with two namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml file that uses two namespaces for game and dlc. Im now trying to do simple xls tranformation to html as table. But I cant get it to work and I have pinned the problem and it has to be something with namespaces. The html is always blank, there is only table headers. Im 100% sure that schemas work because xml validation doesnt give any errors.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<GameStore xmlns="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/game"
           xmlns:d="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/dlc"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/game Steam-kauppa.xsd http://www.steamkauppa.fi/dlc SteamDLC.xsd">
    <Game>
        <Name>Borderlands 2</Name>  
        <Category>Action Games</Category>
        <ReleaseDate>21 Sep 2012</ReleaseDate>
        <Developer>Gearbox Software</Developer>
        <AgeLimit>18</AgeLimit>
        <Description>A new era of shoot and loot is about to begin. Play as one 
            of four new vault hunters facing off against a massive new world of 
            creatures, psychos and the evil mastermind, Handsome Jack. Make new 
            friends, arm them with a bazillion weapons and fight alongside them 
            in 4 player co-op on a relentless quest for revenge and redemption 
            across the undiscovered and unpredictable living planet.</Description>
        <Price currency = "EUR">29.99</Price>
        <DiscountPercent>75</DiscountPercent>
        <DLCPacks>
            <DLC>
                <d:Name>Borderlands 2 - Psycho Pack</d:Name>
                <d:Price currency = "EUR">9.99</d:Price>
                <d:DiscountPercent>67</d:DiscountPercent>
            </DLC>    
            <DLC>
                <d:Name>Borderlands 2: Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 2</d:Name>
                <d:Price currency = "EUR">3.99</d:Price>
                <d:DiscountPercent>67</d:DiscountPercent>
            </DLC>      
        </DLCPacks>
    </Game>

    <Game>
        <Name>7 Days to Die</Name>  
        <Category>Action Games</Category>
        <ReleaseDate>13 Dec 2013</ReleaseDate>
        <Developer>The Fun Pimps</Developer>
        <AgeLimit>18</AgeLimit>
        <Description>Building on survivalist and horror themes, players in 7 
            Days to Die can scavenge the abandoned cities of the buildable and 
            destructable voxel world for supplies or explore the wilderness to 
            gather raw materials to build their own tools, weapons, traps, 
            fortifications and shelters. In coming updates these features will 
            be expanded upon with even more depth and a wider variety of choices
            to survive the increasing dangers of the world. Play alone or with 
            friends, run your own server or join others.</Description>
        <Price currency = "EUR">22.99</Price>    
        <DiscountAmount>12</DiscountAmount>   
    </Game>       
</GameStore>
```

schema file 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<xsd:schema version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/game"
            xmlns="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/game"
            xmlns:d="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/dlc"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/dlc" 
       schemaLocation="SteamDLC.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="Price">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xsd:double">
                    <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Category" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="ReleaseDate" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Developer" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="AgeLimit" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="DiscountPercent" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="DiscountAmount" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="gameType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Name"/>
            <xsd:element ref="Category"/>
            <xsd:element ref="ReleaseDate"/>
            <xsd:element ref="Developer"/>
            <xsd:element ref="AgeLimit"/>
            <xsd:element ref="Description"/>  
            <xsd:element ref="Price"/>  
            <xsd:element ref="DiscountPercent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element ref="DiscountAmount" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>  
            <xsd:element ref="DLCPacks" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


    <xsd:element name="GameStore">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Game" type="gameType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="DLCPacks">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="DLC" type="d:dlcType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>




</xsd:schema>
```

schema file 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<xsd:schema version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/dlc"
            xmlns="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/dlc" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="Price">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xsd:double">
                    <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="DiscountPercent" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="DiscountAmount" type="xsd:int"/>


    <xsd:complexType name="dlcType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Name"/> 
            <xsd:element ref="Price"/>  
            <xsd:element ref="DiscountPercent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>   
            <xsd:element ref="DiscountAmount" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>  
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>



</xsd:schema>
```

xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Category</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="GameStore/Game">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Category"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read some tutorials about XML namespaces it has been asked and answered a lot here on stackoverflow.com.

In your XML input there is a default namespace declared `xmlns="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/game"`, meaning all unprefixed elements in your input belong to that namespace.

So to be able to do an XSLT transformation on these elements, add the namespace to your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:game="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/game" exclude-result-prefixes="game">
```

Now that the namespace is declared in your XSLT, you should use it, see next adjustements:

```
<xsl:for-each select="game:GameStore/game:Game">
<xsl:value-of select="game:Name"/>
```

Complete adjusted XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:game="http://www.steamkauppa.fi/game" exclude-result-prefixes="game">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Category</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="game:GameStore/game:Game">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="game:Name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="game:Category"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could use namespaces and dont have to use prefixes for default namespace like in my xml file?

Comment: default namespaces in your XSLT only work for elements 'to be created'. For XPath you will need a prefixed namespace